# something about android mp3 play

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    playOrderSound();
    super.onResume();
}
private void playOrderSound(Context context){
    player= MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.order);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.reset();
            player.release();
        }
    });
    player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            player.start();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I put the sound source in the raw directory and use mediaPlayer to play it.When the server send message to me.I start a new activity and play the mp3 resource,but it does't work.
the new activity start with lauchmode singletask.

Comment: You must set ```player.prepare()``` or ```player.prepareAsync()``` before ```start()```

Comment: i create the player by create ,so if i set prepare(),some error occured

Comment: Sorry, I will check again

Comment: onResume() I think you missing `()` at `playOrderSound`;

Comment: i delete the () when i edit the question,sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Playing Well**

```
   @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            super.onResume();
            playOrderSound(Mainactivity.this);



        }

        private void playOrderSound(Context context){

            player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.acc);
            player.start();


            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    player.reset();
                    player.release();
                }
            });
            player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    player.start();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();


            player.stop();

            }
```

Comment: it  works when i delete player.setOnCompletionLisener(),thank you

Comment: Accept Answer if this is helping for you